# Data Transfer Rate

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

This may be a very newbie question but I am just confused in general about the following. I have a 300Mbps router (wireless-N) and with my ISP, I have a 15Mbps download rate.

So my question is, what is the point of having a 300Mbps router if the max that can be downloaded is only ~15Mbps?

once again, sorry if this is a newbie question, it just doesn't make sense to me.

hope someone can clear this confusion. thank you.

Comment: Many people transfer data within their own network, and so 300mbps is useful.

Answer (score 0):

300Mbps is just the advertised data rate, throughput will definitely be lower (but much higher than 15Mbps).

Anyway, your 300Mbps bandwidth is between the WiFi connected PCs and your router, and to any other device connected to the same router. So, if you have two PCs and you share data between them you'll get much higher throughput than 15MBps.

Comment: So it's really only beneficial when there are multiple PC's involved?  Does that mean that ~20 PC's all with data transfer rates of ~15Mbps can be achieved? (15Mbps*20 = 300Mbps).

Comment: @user41580 No, your internet speed is limited to 15Mbps, and will be shared between all machines on your local network. You can transfer between machines on your local network at up to 300Mbps (minus overheads and loss, of course).